# issue cycling through forms with different names in django views

Tags: django, forms

I am working on a project and i am having an issue with djago form templates and it only returning one part of the form.

So what is happening is:
I have a ModelForm that contains two fields which are amount and description. Within the view I cycle through a list of users. for every user in the loop it creates a form with the users username prefix and then passes the list of forms into the html template.

The issue that i am having is that all of the forms and their prefixes are passing to the html tempalte, but when it is submitted, only the last form is passed back to be proccessed. I have an example below and the file info that is related to this issue.

**Please look at the updated section at the bottom of the question**

Here are the passed in forms that were created in the view before html template is displayed:

```
omarform
<tr><th><label for="id_omar-amount">Amount:</label></th><td><input id="id_omar-amount" name="omar-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_omar-description">Description:</label></th><td><input id="id_omar-description" maxlength="250" name="omar-description" type="text" /></td></tr>
haniform
<tr><th><label for="id_hani-amount">Amount:</label></th><td><input id="id_hani-amount" name="hani-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_hani-description">Description:</label></th><td><input id="id_hani-description" maxlength="250" name="hani-description" type="text" /></td></tr>
ranaform
<tr><th><label for="id_rana-amount">Amount:</label></th><td><input id="id_rana-amount" name="rana-amount" step="0.01" type="number" value="0.0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_rana-description">Description:</label></th><td><input id="id_rana-description" maxlength="250" name="rana-description" type="text" /></td></tr>
```

Here is what is displayed correctly:

```
fill out the form below
Amount: 
0.0
Description: 
Amount: 
0.0
Description: 
Amount: 
0.0
Description: 
Tax: 
Tip: 
submit
```

but here is what is returned when i try to submit the form:

```
Request information

GET
No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
rana-amount '0.0'
rana-description    ''
tax ''
tip ''
submit  'submit'
```

---

Here is the code:

html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Add members to {{record.name}}</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

views:

```
def addTransaction(request, groupId, recordId):
    user = User.objects.get(username='omar')
    group = Group.objects.get(id=groupId)
    record = Record.objects.get(id=recordId)
    transactions = Transaction.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                amount = cd['amount']
                description = cd['description']
                split_amount = SplitEven(record, amount)
                for trans in transactions:
                    if trans.record.id == record.id:
                        trans.description = description
                        trans.amount = split_amount
                        trans.save()
                return redirect('accounts')
        if record.split == 2:
            form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(requesst.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                for trans in transactions:
                    if trans.record.id == record.id:
                        amount = 'desiatnace'

        # even_form = EvenSplitTransactionForm(request.POST)
        # if even_form.is_valid():
        #     even_cd = even_form.cleaned_data
        #     amount = even_cd['amount']
        #     description = even_cd['description']
        #     if record.split == 1:
        #         split_amount = SplitEven(record, amount)
        #         for trans in transactions:
        #             if trans.record.id == record.id:
        #                 trans.description = description
        #                 trans.amount = split_amount
        #                 trans.save()
        #     if record.split == 2:
        #         splits = amount
        return redirect('accounts')
    else:
        if record.split == 1:
            form = EvenSplitTransactionForm()
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_even_transactions.html', parameters)
        if record.split == 2:
            for trans in transactions:
                if trans.record.id == record.id:
                    formName = trans.user.username + 'form'
                    print(formName)
                    form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(prefix=trans.user.username)
                    print(form)
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_individual_transaction.html', parameters)
```

form:

```
class IndividualSplitTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['amount', 'description']
```

**UPDATED**

I was in the template file and i deleted some of the commented code and i found out that only the last form of the three that i am passing into the template is beign displayed and bragged by the template. So the real issue that I realized that i am having is that i need to pas three forms and only one is being passed. i need to figure out how to combine all three of the forms into one and pass it or pass all three forms individually with different names within the for loop.

This is what i with the form before it is being passed through...

```
if record.split == 2:
            for trans in transactions:
                if trans.record.id == record.id:
                    formName = trans.user.username + 'form'
                    form = IndividualSplitTransactionForm(prefix=trans.user.username)
                    print(form)
            message = 'fill out the form below'
            parameters = {
                'record':record,
                'form':form,
                'message':message,
                'transactions':transactions,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/add_individual_transaction.html', parameters)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you have multiple 'amount', 'description' fields in one form.

for example, you have Sarah, Pill, Kelly. You have three each fields in your form like below.

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
## Sarah section
<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="text" name="description">
## Pill section
<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="text" name="description">
## Kelly section
<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="text" name="description">
<button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I assume that you use same name 'amount' and 'desciption'. So if you get data from `request.POST.get('amount', None)`, you will get only last data. Try with `request.POST.getlist('amount')`.

You can check in your console screen with `print(request.POST);`

Comment: you are pretty close to what i am trying to get... the forms names would be sarah-amount, sarah-description, pill-amount, pill-description, kelly-amount, kelly-description. the issue is that when i access the submitted data in the view, i am only getting kelly-amount, kelly-description...

I will try waht you suggested, but would i use the request.POST.getlist('amount') after i check to see if form is valid, to when would i use the request.POST.getlist()...

Comment: I found what is causing the problem can you look at the updated tab of the original post.

Comment: I updated the question becasue i found out what the actual problem was and why nothing was passing but i still need help figuring out why... @Jayground

Comment: In forloop `for trans in transaction`, you just update form variable. So you just pass very last form variable in context. I assume that you just want to make multiple forms to save in same model(same table in database). Why don't you check formset? [formset django manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/)